# Broadcast when the system is about to turn the CPU off

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to be notified when the system is about to go to sleep to preserve the battery on Android?

There is for example:

[Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)

However, is there any way to set a callback when when the system is about to put the CPU to sleep?

Comment: Dreaming is just a sort of screensaver, which can activate when the device is docked but can also be disabled by the user. It doesn't really have anything to do with CPU sleep.

Comment: I doubt the cpu will ever be turned off when android is in standby.

Comment: @Goot it will. Check this for example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: @Nick Oh, yes, forgot about this new feature ;) Thanks! :)